# Listening to coroutine from view cant be done from the views init

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to listen to my ViewModels `MutableStateFlow` from my `FlutterSceneView`. But I get the following error when trying to set the listener from the views init:

`Suspend function 'listenToBackgroundColor' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`

```
class FlutterSceneView(context: Context, private val viewModel: FlutterSceneViewModelType): PlatformView {
    private val context = context
    private val sceneView = SceneView(context)

    init {
        listenToBackgroundColor() // Error here
    }

    private suspend fun listenToBackgroundColor() {
        viewModel.colorFlow.collect {
            val newColor = Color.parseColor(it)
            sceneView.setBackgroundColor(newColor)
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
interface FlutterSceneViewModelType {
    var colorFlow: MutableStateFlow<String>
}

class FlutterSceneViewModel(private val database: Database): FlutterSceneViewModelType, ViewModel() {
    override var colorFlow = MutableStateFlow<String>("#FFFFFF")

    init {
            listenToBackgroundColorFlow()
    }

    private fun listenToBackgroundColorFlow() {
        database.backgroundColorFlow.watch {
            colorFlow.value = it.hex
        }
    }
}
```

the `.watch` call is a helper I have added so that this can be exposed to iOS using Kotlin multi-platform, it looks as follows but I can use `collect` instead if necessary:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.asCommonFlow(): CommonFlow<T> = CommonFlow(this)
class CommonFlow<T>(private val origin: Flow<T>) : Flow<T> by origin {
    fun watch(block: (T) -> Unit): Closeable {
        val job = Job()

        onEach {
            block(it)
        }.launchIn(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job))

        return object : Closeable {
            override fun close() {
                job.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only call suspend functions from coroutines. I'm not sure how else to help, because it's odd that you wouldn't know that, but do know what a Flow is, which is more advanced than the coroutine basics.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using viewModel context:

```
    private fun listenToBackgroundColor() {
        viewModel.colorFlow.onEach {
            val newColor = Color.parseColor(it)
            sceneView.setBackgroundColor(newColor)
        }.launchIn(viewModel.viewModelScope)
    }
```

I had to import the following into my ViewModel:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
```

from:

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0")
```